# I am getting a prop mutation error when passing from child to child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent component, which has a child component that has a child component.
The parent passes data to the first child as a prop.
What I want to do is to forward this prop to the second child, and then I want to compare the data in that prop with data in my second child, and if that data contains an identical result, then it needs to stop a method in the second child from running.

The problem is that just passing the prop from child 1 to child 2 causes a prop mutation warning.

The parent:

```
<template>
   <div>
     <child-one :my-data="myData"/>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    data() {
      return {
        myData: [ some data... ]
      }
    }
</script>
```

Child one

```
<template>
   <div>
     <button @click="openModal">Open second child</button>
     <child-two :my-data="myData" ref="openChildTwoModal"/>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   props: { myData: Array }
   methods: {
      openModal() {
        this.$refs['openChildTwoModal'].open
       }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child two

```
<template>
   <div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   props: { myData: Array }
    data() {
      return {
        showModal: false
        myOtherData: [ some other data... ]
      }
    }
   methods: {
      open() {
        this.showModal = true
       }
    checkIfSimilarIdExists() {
      if (this.myData.some(data => data.id === this.myOtherData.id)) {
        console.log('There is a duplicate ID!')
      }
    },
    }
  }
</script>
```

I tried creating a new variable in child one, where I could pass the data from the prop, so I wouldn't mutate it directly.
Like:

```
mounted() {
  this.newDataList = this.myData
}
```

but still getting the mutated prop error.

I was thinking of using emit, but then remembered that emit goes the opposite way from child two to child one to parent.

Why can't I pass the prop from child one to two?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#composition-api-dependency-injection

Comment: I couldn't reproduce. I don't see anywhere in your code where `myData` is being mutated.  Passing it as a prop multiple levels shouldn't by itself cause the error.  I'm wondering if there's any other uses of `myData` in your code not shown in your question.  It would also be helpful to include the full exact error in your question, with stacktrace if possible.

Comment: Regarding your attempted fix. `this.newDataList = this.myData` creates a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) and would not fix the issue.  You need a deep copy, e.g. `this.newDataList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myData))`

Comment: Correct way is to use Vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html). Create a store for an object. Use getter to get object value and use mutation to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Child two`, you can use [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone), so that it won't mutate it's parent data.

Here's an example on `child two` component, you can `computed` to access the data like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ nonMutatedData }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  props: { myData: Array }
   data() {
     return {
       showModal: false
       myOtherData: [ some other data... ]
     }
   }
  methods: {
     open() {
       this.showModal = true
      },
   checkIfSimilarIdExists() {
     if (this.myData.some(data => data.id === this.myOtherData.id)) {
       console.log('There is a duplicate ID!')
     }
   },
   }
   computed: {
    nonMutatedData() {
      const clonedData = structuredClone(this.myData)
      return clonedData
    }
   }
 }
</script>
```